# can i publicate swift app with "hack" which is due to NSAllowsArbitraryLoads?

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

I am developing an application in swift, which is writing into database. But I am using below solution for transporting data

[image]

Reference : https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSnGS.png

This application will be used only in my company of 6 members approximately, but it should go through the apple control. Do you think, it can go through the control? I heard, that my solution is only "hack" but I can not find anything better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit an application with this configuration. And it is not any kind of hack. It just means that you are allowing every type of url loading in your application, whether it is with **SSL** (https) or not.

If you don't set `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` to `true`, then your app will block access to urls that don't use **SSL** (https).

Apple's recommendation is that your application should only allow connections using SSL (via the SDK's APIs or third party frameworks), **for better security**

That's it!

But your app will **not** be rejected if you don't follow this guideline.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation